# How to pass body content to gmail Rest API?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I need to pass email content to gmail rest API.

I am using the following input to convert into Base64 and pass it to gmail api  {"raw":"Base64content"} and userId in **Try this API** area from https://developers.google.com

**Input to convert to Base64:**
From: from@email.com
To: to@email.com
Subject: Test email check!
Body:Hello from user!

I am not even getting email. If i remove "Body:Hello from user!" I am getting an email.

If anyone faced/solved this kind of issues?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just give an empty line after subject content and give whatever plain text you want as follows:
From: from@email.com 
To: 
to@email.com 
Subject:Test email check!

Hello from user!

If you want to send html content,try this

From: from@email.com 
To: to@email.com 
Subject:Test email check!
 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

```
<h1>Welcome User!</h1>
```

Hope it helps.